# querydsl - list condition

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, querydsl

that's my code :

```
final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
final List<Tuple> myList = query
                .from(QPerson.person)
                    .groupBy(QPerson.person.name)
                    .where(myBooleanExpression) //myBooleanExpression declared at the top of code              
                    .list(QPerson.person.name, 
                          QPerson.person.cash.sum());
```

What i want to do is to list :

- name (*without condition*)
- sum(cash) *ONLY IF (condition), ELSE (..)*

Any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: well didnt you Kind of solved it at your own - you Loop through the list and have a Output list and in the Loop you make your if-else ...

Comment: @mayha thanks for your suggestion, can you make me a code example please? i would like to understand it better. Sorry but i am  newbbie with querydsl and the doc (http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch03.html) is really poor..

Comment: that depends in what Format you Need the Output - if you just wanna Show it somewhere you can save as a string ...

Comment: @mayha i have to take the name as String, cash.sum as BigDecimal and fill a Bean having two properties with the respective types

Comment: Or, you could use an SQL CASE with a [CaseBuilder](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/CaseBuilder.html) in the `list()` method call.

Comment: @pozs thanks for your reply, I've already tried it before as you said but without any success, the doc doesn't show me the sintax about how to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an SQL `CASE` in your case, like:

```
final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
final List<Tuple> myList = query
    .from(QPerson.person)
    .groupBy(QPerson.person.name)
    .where(myBooleanExpression)
    .list(QPerson.person.name, 
          new CaseBuilder()
              .when(yourOtherBooleanExpression).then(QPerson.person.cash.sum())
              .otherwise(yourOtherNumericExpressionOrLiteral));
```

- `yourOtherBooleanExpression` should be a `Predicate` (like `BooleanExpression`)
- `yourOtherNumericExpressionOrLiteral` should be a `NumberExpression<T>` or `T` itself, where `T` is the base type of `QPerson.person.cash`.

Comment: @lbat I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can use as many `CASE` construct in your query (and therefore `CaseBuilder` instances) as you want. The rule of thumb for them is that they need to use compatible types in their `THEN` and `ELSE` cases (`then()` and `otherwise()` methods).